# Across several columns, count instances of pairs

Tags: r, dplyr, count, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I want to count pairs across several columns. That is, with more than two columns, count the number of times particular value pairs occur in the same row.

Say I asked some people whether they liked different kinds of food, and they could answer "yes" or "no". I ended up with this data set:

```
foods <- 
  data.frame(
    fruit = c("yes", "yes", "no"),
    veg = c("yes", "yes", "yes"),
    meat = c("yes", "no", "yes")
  )
foods
```

I'd like to count the number of times any two foods received a "yes". I hope to end up with something like this:

```
desired <- 
  data.frame(
    pair.1 = c("fruit", "fruit", "veg"),
    pair.2 = c("veg", "meat", "meat"),
    Freq = c(2, 1, 2)
  )
desired
```

This could also work:

```
desired.2 <- 
  data.frame(
    pair. = c("fruit, veg", "fruit, meat", "veg, meat"),
    Freq = c(2, 1, 2)
  )
desired.2
```

If possible, I hope I could use a solution to eventually do the same for combinations of 3, 4, and so on (my actual data has more than 3 columns). What's a good solution to this, preferably using dplyr?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` solution could be:

```
map_dfr(.x = combn(names(foods), 2, simplify = FALSE),
        ~ foods %>%
         select(.x) %>%
         summarise(pair_1 = .x[1],
                   pair_2 = .x[2],
                   n = sum(rowSums(select(., everything()) == "yes") == 2)))

  pair_1 pair_2 n
1  fruit    veg 2
2  fruit   meat 1
3    veg   meat 2
```

If you want something more generalizable:

```
fun <- function(x) {
map_dfr(.x = combn(names(foods), x, simplify = FALSE),
        ~ foods %>%
         select(.x) %>%
         summarise(pairs = paste(.x, collapse = " "),
                   n = sum(rowSums(select(., everything()) == "yes") == x)))
}

fun(2)

       pairs n
1  fruit veg 2
2 fruit meat 1
3   veg meat 2
```

Comment: Both of these work great. What if I wanted to change the yes in `everything()) == "yes"` to something equivalent to "not NA". Do you think there's a straightforward way to implement that tweak?

Comment: How about `!is.na(select(., everything()))`?

Comment: Ah, I feel silly now. Yes, that works exactly the way I needed. Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combn`, i.e.

```
combn(names(foods), 2, FUN = function(i){i1 <- foods[i]; sum(i1[1] == i1[2])})
#[1] 2 1 2
```

Comment: For me, this returned the error: `Error in Ops.factor(left, right) : level sets of factors are different`

Comment: You need to convert from factor to character

Answer (score 1):

For pairs, it sounds like you're looking for `crossprod`:

```
crossprod(foods == "yes")
#       fruit veg meat
# fruit     2   2    1
# veg       2   3    2
# meat      1   2    2
```

Note the `upper.tri` or `lower.tri` of the result above.

If we treat the result as a `table`, we can wrap it in `data.frame` and extract just those specific pairs:

```
x <- crossprod(foods == "yes")
data.frame(as.table(x))[lower.tri(x), ]
#   Var1  Var2 Freq
# 2  veg fruit    2
# 3 meat fruit    1
# 6 meat   veg    2
```